# How to use SFTP with PhpStorm to access server /var/www folder

Tags: php, ssh, permissions, phpstorm, sftp

I am trying to use PhpStorm with remote server project, but unfortunately I cannot success in SFTP configuration.

I have followed these steps [SFTP www](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143700/granting-a-sftp-user-access-to-a-var-www-directory). But I still get the same error ...

```
Write failed: Broken pipe
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

My ssh-config:

```
UsePAM yes
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match user www-data
ChrootDirectory /var/www
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Permissions

```
chown root:root /var/www
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/site
```

I have tried different ways, but still the same problem.

How to do this correctly, because it is real project, and I am worrying about wrong permissions.

Please help to solve this problem, I have spent several hours already dealing with it.

Comment: You'd be better off asking this question on serverfault.com.

Comment: Are you able to connect to your SFTP server using another app (e.g. FileZilla or whatever you have got there on your OS)?